# What is the derivation of an integral?

Tags: derivatives, improper-integrals, partial-derivative

Given an intergral 
$$
\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} f(t, x) dx
$$
What is the fomula to of its derivation?
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} f(t, x) dx
$$

Would someone please give me a link to the fomula and its derivations?

**EDIT**:

The answer is 
$$
\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} f'_t(t, x)dx 
+ f(t, b(t)) b'_t(t)
- f(t, a(t)) a'_t(t)
$$
and [here(Leibniz_integral_rule)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) is the reference.

Many thanks to [André Nicolas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/andre-nicolas)'s comment!

Comment: [This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to the Leibniz Integral Rule may help. You can also search under that name, or under the name differentiation under the integral sign.

Comment: @Integrator: Ordinarily when a simple link is involved, with no "added value" I prefer to just leave a comment, but I ca see your point, the site explicitly discourages that.

Answer (score 2):

By the [Leibniz Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) for differentiation under the integral sign, we have
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} f(t,x)\,dx =b'(t)f(t,b(t))-a'(t)f(t,a(t))+  \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,x)\,dx                  .$$
For details, please see the Wikipedia article linked to above.